# Want to skip textbox based on tabindex property

Tags: javascript, html

There are 5 textbox in one row, and each textbox has one specific checkbox.When i checked the 3rd the checkbox at that time when i am tabing means from 1st textbox i press TAB KEY then it will go to 2nd textbox and when i will press one another time TAB KEY ,now this time it will skipp the 3rd textbox(because this time i have checked the 3rd checkbox.)Make sure this time i am also able to add value in textbox.Only just want to do is during tabing 3rd textbox will be skipe.`enter code here`

```
<head>
    <title>TAB PROGRAM</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- define the toggle function -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggleState(item) {

            if (document.getElementById("check" + item).checked == true) {

                document.getElementById("realname" + (item + 1)).focus();

            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form ACTION="" METHOD=POST>
        <table BORDER CELLPADDING=10 CELLSPACING=10>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Full name:
                    <input type="text" id="relanme1" tabindex="1" onfocus="toggleState(1)">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" value="check1" tabindex="-1">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="realname2" class="test" onfocus="toggleState(2)">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" value="check2" tabindex="-1" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="realname3" class="test" onfocus="toggleState(3)">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check3" value="check3" tabindex="-1" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="realname4" class="test" onfocus="toggleState(4)">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check4" value="check4" tabindex="-1" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="realname5" class="test" onfocus="toggleState(5)">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check5" value="check5" tabindex="-1" />
                </td>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `tabindex` of the `input` each time you click the checkbox. This will skip the element when you navigate using <kbd>TAB</kbd>, but it will not prevent to get the focus whe you click on it

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="realnme1" tabindex="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" value="check1" tabindex="-1" onchange="toggle('1')">
```

JS:

```
function toggle(item) {
    if ($('#check' + item).is(':checked') ) {
        $('#realname' + item).prop('tabindex', -1);
    } else {
        $('#realname' + item).prop('tabindex', item);
    }
}
```

Here you can find the full example:
http://jsfiddle.net/owrazh7h/1/